# Macro to group rows by fill color does nothing and I am not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro capable of grouping rows based on their fill color. The issue is: my macro does nothing. It neither groups the rows nor throws an error. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowGrouper()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Cells
        If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = (xlNone Or RGB(255, 255, 238)) Then
                '255,255,238 is the light yellow color in the images below
            rng.Rows.Group
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help you can lend me is appreciated.

Here is a picture of the rows I am trying to group and one of them grouped as they should be:

[image: Pre-grouping] [image: Post-grouping]

Edit: With the help of Michael Murphy, I am getting closer, but now it is only group the light yellow rows, rather than all of the white and light yellow rows.

[image]

Comment: Are the cells coloured "manually" or with conditional formatting?

Comment: They come colored from the database I am downloading the sheets from. So, close enough to manually, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = (xlNone Or RGB(255, 255, 238)) Then
```

you'll need to change this to

```
If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Or rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 238) Then
```

In the future you should try stepping through your code line-by-line. You'd be able to see that your `If` always evaluates to `False` no matter what color your cell is.

Comment: Yes, though I think it should be `Color` rather than `ColorIndex` (at least for the second one).

Comment: Thank you for your help! That certainly got me closer to the answer. I edited my question because now it is only group the yellow rows instead of both the yellow and white rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the immediate window to check the white cells for either the `Selection.Interior.ColorIndex` or the `Selection.Interior.Color` and use that in your `If` statement instead of the `xlNone` piece. If you need more help I'd suggest you mark this solution and ask a new question for better visibility.