# Grouping Rows based on whether text is bold

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro that will automatically group (collapse) all rows when the text in column A is not in bold. I do not have any code yet, however when I have done it before based on cell color, [code taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539862/macro-to-group-rows-by-fill-color-does-nothing-and-i-am-not-sure-why), it has not worked based on the solution provided. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Rows as they appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMhb5.png)

[Rows when they are grouped, which I have done manually.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNUQc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read your additional info on Conditional Formatting.

So, in that case you can simply use the `DisplayFormat` method and run the same method.

```
Sub SetGroups()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range, pCell As Range
    
    'Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary => use if adding the reference 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
    'Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim dict As Object '=> use when NOT adding the reference 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange
    
    'Set grouping button to top row
    With ws.Outline
        .AutomaticStyles = False
        .SummaryRow = xlAbove
        .SummaryColumn = xlRight
    End With
    
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        
        If pCell Is Nothing Then
            Set pCell = cell
        End If

        'If cell.Font.Bold And Not dict.Exists(cell.row) Then  
        If cell.DisplayFormat.Font.Bold And Not dict.Exists(cell.row) Then
            dict.Add cell.row, cell.row
            Set pCell = cell
        End If
        
        If dict.Exists(pCell.row) Then
            dict.Item(pCell.row) = cell.row
        End If
    Next
    
    'ungroup all used rows
    rng.Rows.ClearOutline
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        If (dict(Key) > Key) Then
            Range(Rows(Key + 1), Rows(dict(Key))).Rows.Group
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @bargainyield, Updated the method to reflect the Conditional Formatting

Answer (score 1):

I updated the code you referenced to check the `Range.Font.Bold` property. This code assumes `A` as the column with bold values.

```
Sub RowGrouper()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Cells
        If rng.Font.Bold Then
            rng.Rows.Group
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this more or less works. However in some documents I've applied it to it doesn't work because the bolds are conditionally formatted.